# Is there a performance benefit to shipping Web Assembly vs minified Javascript?

Tags: javascript, webassembly

Is there a performance benefit from serving Javascript compiled to Web Assembly (perhaps by AssemblyScript?), vs minified Javascript?

I'm specifically thinking about:

- [parse / compile time](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/javascript-startup-optimization/)
- execution time
- byte size
- memory usage
- how CDNs interact with it (serving binary application/wasm vs text application/javascript)

Comment: WebAssembly is an experimental technology and doesn't have JIT compilation yet.

Comment: WebAssembly  is no more experimental..., It can directly compile to machine code. Google V8 uses Liftoff for compiling it.

Comment: Actual there is an big performance issue. Consider someone build an engine with WebAssembly VM for scripting. WASM will run at some speed while JavaScript will fail to execute.

Answer (score 2):

> parse / compile time

Well it's already compiled, that's the whole point of WASM.  If you mean from ByteCode to Nativecode, this should be much faster than from Javascript to Native code.

> execution time

Yes, faster, again it's kind of the whole point.

> byte size

Debatable here, I think minified Javascript is pretty efficient here.

> memory usage

WebAsembly is meant to compliment Javascript, so in theory it's the same,..

> how CDNs interact with it (serving binary application/wasm vs text application/javascript)

A CDN it's just a place to ship assets, so I can't see this been an issue. eg.  Fonts and images are binary, and they work fine.  BTW, wasm comes with the same security policy's as Javascript, so it's not like shipping an EXE over the wire.